# How to get preview of the email body

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

I want to get the first 255 character of email body. Like in Outlook we have on our left panel we see list of emails displayed with one line of message body. I wanted to get preview of an email message.

Any inbuilt api from ews is good rather than doing string manipulation
Can anyone please help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question lacks a lot of relevant context. So please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question to further enhance your question.

Comment: Do you have any code to show what you did so far? Can you get the whole body and just trim it to 255 characters?

Comment: i have read one article says we have something like Item.Preview where it shows first 255 character , i am not able to see that method in class.

Comment: @Karthik tn which class? Which library or API are you trying to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly but in case you just want to get the first 255 characters of an existing string you can use:

```
String message; //String that holds your message
String previewMessage = ""; //String to store your pewview message

if(message.length() >= 255) {
  previewMessage = message.substring(0, 254);
}
```